# Wordpress Plugin - Request WPDB with AJAX

Tags: wordpress

I need a request WPDB with AJAX in a wordpress admin plugin

The method $Cidade->inserirCidade when execute only, this works fine, but when the method is called with AJAX, give me the ERROR in console -> POST http://wordpress.loc/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 500 (Internal Server Error)

```
private function __construct() {        
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', array( $this, 'my_action' ));
    add_action( 'admin_footer', array ( $this, 'my_action_javascript' ));
}

public static function my_action_javascript() { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        var data = {
            'action': 'my_action',
            'codigo': 222
        };

        jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
        });
    });
    </script> <?php
}

public function my_action() {

    $codigo = intval( $_POST['codigo'] );
    $nome = 'Meu Nome';
    $ibge = 123;
    $uf = 'DF';

    $Cidade = new Cidade;
    $result = $Cidade->inserirCidade($codigo, $nome, $ibge, $uf);

    wp_die(); // this is required to terminate immediately and return a proper response
}
```

I receive the error in console -> POST http://wordpress.loc/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Hi! This means that there is an error somewhere in your code. I always comment-out every line and start uncommenting/debugging line by line to see which line causes the error. If you know that, I can help you further. Have you enabled WP_DEBUG and does your environment shows PHP errors?

Comment: BTW, if this AJAX endpoint needs to be accessible by non-loggedin users, you also need to define the nopriv action: add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', array( $this, 'my_action' ));

Comment: Can you please post the rest of the relevant code for this?